# SSRS show average column in metrics report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have to show average columns on right and bottom of a SSRS matrix report under.

```
        B       C       D       E       F       G       H       I       TOTAL   
ABC     0       0       0       0       0       0       2       0       2       7.14%
PQR     0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       1       3.57%
KLM     5       4       5       0       4       4       0       0       22      78.57%
HIJ     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0.00%
XYZ     1       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       3       10.71%
TOTAL   6       5       5       1       4       4       2       1       28      100.00%
    21.43%  17.86%  17.86%  3.57%   14.29%  14.29%  7.14%   3.57%   100.00%
```

I have completed all other columns i.e. `Total`, but stuck to get average in last row and last column.

Thanks

Comment: Please, show the expression with which you get error.

Comment: Hi
I didn't get any error, infect I don't know how to formulate this average in SSRS.

I can do it if somehow i can refer the last cell of "Total Column" contain value 28, Can someone tell me how to refer that cell  in Expression?

Comment: You can refer to specified cell as `ReportItem!cell_name.Value`. But it's a bad  practice. How you get values in column and row named `Total`?

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, I got value of column named total as "=Sum(Fields!MyFieldName.Value)"

Plus ReportItem!cell_name.Value this will not work for me as it will give different value for different rows, I need to pick only last value , the filed that contain 28, or any other way to get my required average

Comment: Hi Thanks for help, your answer is helpful but I cant mark it as correct answer as its not my actual requirement, I still need the exact solution, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get average value:

```
=Avg(Fields!MyFieldName.Value)
```